# How can i insert a list of dictionaries into my existing item

Tags: python, dictionary, pymongo, updates

I want to insert something in Python 3.8 with Pymongo
I got a short question. I have a list of dictionaries called items:

```
item_list = [{'name': 'abc', 'category': 'cde', 'assurance': 0.9844486508518457, 'count': 1},
            {'name': 'abc', 'category': 'cde', 'assurance': 0.7428154349327087, 'count': 1},
            {'name': 'abc', 'category': 'cde', 'assurance': 0.9954652488231659, 'count': 1}]
```

I also have my database item:

```
item = collection.find_one(<placeholder>)
```

Now I tried the following:

```
collection.update_one(item, {"$set": {"Entity": item_list} }, True)
```

But this does not work... How can I insert a list of dictionaries?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you've in item ? Did you get an error ? Or first can you check if there is any document matched with filter query i.e; item, if there are multiple can you check if anyone of those got updated !!

Comment: in my item tooks like the following: item{"name":"test"}. any i already checked if my item is matched. I get the following error message:
"TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping"

Comment: you mean to say your placeholder is valid and giving you a DB document in `item`?

Comment: This is failing because `item` is a cursor and therefore not a valid filter for the `update_one` function. You will likely want a dictionary, in your case this could be what you were using for the original filter `<placeholder>` Though it's hard to say without seeing what that is

Comment: I found my Problem... The Item was not given and therefore None... Like you said. Thank you!